# What happens to the text in functions.php file outside of the php enclosure?

Tags: functions

I have a very basic question.

In the `functions.php` file of a theme, what happens to the text that is outside a function and outside the <?php ?> tags? Can I place notes before and after the functions without commenting it and without affecting the system? Or should I at least enclose the out-of-php text in html comments?

For example:

```
comment/note/reference text
<?php
function my_function() {
code;
return results;
}
?>
more comment/note/reference text
<?php
function my_function_2() {
code;
return results;
}
?>
more comment/note/reference text
```

cheers,
Gregory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably throw a 'Headers already sent' error/warning and cause a lot of trouble to everything.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer!

Comment: just saw your answer in action, even with html commented text before the first function. cheers.

Comment: No problem mate! It's good you asked, cuz that error is a heck of a pain in the neck! Cheers! :)